# Creating a new multicharacter script. But get the error cannot set property 'innerhtml' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a new character selector for the game fivem. But now i get a error.
When i try to make a new character he shows up the forum where i can fill out the things. But when i click on confirm data it gives me a black screen. And then the follow error:

> cannot set property 'innerhtml' of null

Script js:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        var data = event.data;

        if (data.action == "ui") {
            if (data.toggle) {
                $('.container').show();
                qbMultiCharacters.resetAll();

                $.post('http://bb-multicharacter/setupCharacters');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    qbMultiCharacters.fadeInDown('.characters-list', '20%', 400);
                    $.post('http://bb-multicharacter/removeBlur');
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                $('.container').fadeOut(250);
                document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML = "";
                $('.character-info').fadeOut(750);
                $('.characters').fadeOut(750);
                qbMultiCharacters.resetAll();
            }
        }

        if (data.action == "setupCharacters") {
            setupCharacters(event.data.characters)
        }

        if (data.action == "setinfo") {
            { document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML = event.data.data; }
        }
        
        if (data.action == "setCharData") {
            { document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = event.data.name; }
            { document.getElementById("citizenid").innerHTML = event.data.cid; }
        }
    });

    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

```html
Html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="nui://game/ui/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>barbaroNNs Multicharacter</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-screen">
                <div class="characters-list">
                    <div id="characters">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--
                <div class="character-info" style="position: absolute; left: 40%; top: 20%; background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20,0.8); font-family: Heebo; color: white; border-radius: 5px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; height: 80px;width: 300px">
                    <i class="material-icons" id="close-reg1">close</i>
                    <span id="name" style="position: relative; font-size: 36px; top: 20%"></span>
                    <br />
                    <span id="citizenid" style="font-size: 12px; position: relative; top: 10%"></span>
            
                    <div class="bottons" style="position: absolute; right: 20px; height: 100%; top: 35%;">
                        <span class="loginBtn" onClick="logintochar()" style="background-color: #44bd32; border-radius: 5px; display:inline-block;padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">Play</span>
                        <span class="deleteBtn" onClick="deletechar()" style="background-color: #c02b2b; border-radius: 5px; display:inline-block;padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; padding-top: 5px;; padding-bottom: 5px;">Delete</span>
                    </div>
                </div>-->

                <div class="character-info" style="position: absolute; height: px; width: auto; min-width: 500px; padding: 10px; top: 15%; left: 37%; background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.92); -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px; rgba(0,0,0,0.44); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.44); box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);;border-top: 5px solid rgb(255, 0, 0)">
                    <i class="material-icons" id="close-reg1">close</i>
                    <div class="charinfo" style="position: relative; top: 7%; color: white">
                        <center>
                            <span id="name" style="font-size: 24px; text-align: center">Shimon Abuhatzera</span><br>
                            <span id="citizenid" style="font-size: 12px">CID: RLAS182371923</span><br>
                        
                            <div style="margin-top: 15px;">
                            <button onClick="deletechar()" class="w3-button w3-round-large w3-red w3-hover-white">Delete</button>
                            <button onClick="logintochar()" class="w3-button w3-round-large w3-green w3-hover-white">Select</button>
                            </div>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="character-register">
                    <div class="characters-register-block-header">
                        <p>Character Registration [English Only]</p>
                        <i class="material-icons" id="close-reg">close</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="char-register-inputs">
                        <input type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="char-reg-input">
                        <input type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="Last name" class="char-reg-input">
                        <input type="text" id="nationality" placeholder="Nationality" class="char-reg-input">
                        <input type="date" id="birthdate" placeholder="Date of birth" min="1900-01-01" max="2999-12-31" class="char-reg-input">
                        <select id="gender" name="gender">
                            <option value="man" selected>Man</option>
                            <option value="woman">Woman</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="character-reg-btn" id="create"><p id="create-text">Confirfffggm data</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="character-delete">
                    <div class="characters-delete-block-header">
                        <p>Remove character</p>
                        <i class="material-icons" id="close-del">close</i>
                    </div>

                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this character?</p>
                    <br>
                    <p id="yeet">All your character data will be deleted and cannot be recovered.</p>

                    <div class="character-acceptdel-btn" id="accept-delete"><p id="accept-text">Remove character</p></div>
                    <div class="character-canceldel-btn" id="cancel-delete"><p id="cancel-text">Back</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</html>
```